# Is there a way to know whether entanglement will happen before doing an operation?

Tags: entanglement, phase-kickback

I applied a controlled phase gate (the phase is $\pi/4$) to qubits in the states $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ and I got interesting states - both qubits have shown phase shift as given below. I came to know from an expert that the qubits are in entangles state. But is there any way to know in advance whether entanglement will happen before  doing an operation? Also, how to read the block sphere?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you're applying a more general controlled-$U$ gate. This gate will *not* entangle the two qubits if either

- the first qubit (the control) is in either the state $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$, or
- the second qubit (the target) is in an eigenstate of $U$.

Otherwise, the initially separable state will become entangled after the action of controlled-$U$. In other words, almost any initial state that you pick will become entangled.

You can see this by considering the 4 basis states
$$
|0\rangle|u\rangle,|1\rangle|u\rangle,|0\rangle|v\rangle,|1\rangle|v\rangle
$$
where $|u\rangle$ and $|v\rangle$ are eigenstates of $U$ (with different eigenvalues $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^{i\phi}$). The action of controlled-$U$ is to map these into
$$
|0\rangle|u\rangle,e^{i\theta}|1\rangle|u\rangle,|0\rangle|v\rangle,e^{i\phi}|1\rangle|v\rangle.
$$
So, imagine the initial state were
$$
(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)|u\rangle.
$$
This would change into
$$
(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta e^{i\theta}|1\rangle)|u\rangle,
$$
which is still separable.

In terms of how to read the Bloch sphere, I'm assuming you mean with respect to the presence of entanglement. Assuming that you're overall two-qubit state is pure (i.e. can be written as a state vector), then the state is separable if the two Bloch vectors are length 1 (touching the surface of the sphere). If the length is shorter than that, as in the current picture, the qubits are entangled.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed and complete answer.